# xhr from web worker IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, blob, cors, web-worker

I'm using webworkers to process some files and send it to Server.
The xhr from webworkers works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari but in IE fails becouse it treats it like a cross domain request. I guess this is about(from MDN):

**Note** : The URI passed as parameter of the `Worker` constructor must obey the [same-origin policy](/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) . There is currently disagreement among browsers vendors on what URIs are of the same-origin; Gecko 10.0 (Firefox 10.0 / Thunderbird 10.0 / SeaMonkey 2.7) and later do allow data URIs and Internet Explorer 10 does not allow Blob URIs as a valid script for workers.

I'm doing an xhr request specifying the absolut path to say navigator that I'm not doing a cors(as i said works well on all navigators except great IE) IE not allow blob uri origin
[image: ie developer tools net requests]

I've seen some related bug notification in Explorer page.
My question is if anyone has some tricky solution on this or maybe i'm doing something wrong

Thank you !

Comment: I figure out what was wrong, and maybe answer helps to someone else. I was sending formData objects from the worker.This is not possible but i find some pollify:https://gist.github.com/lemonhall/3120320/
This pollify works fine in Chrome FF and Safari but not in IE.
I need to make my multipart by hand

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921339/sending-binary-data-using-multipart-form-data-from-a-worker-with-ie11