# Sending binary data using multipart/form-data from a worker with IE11

Tags: file-upload, binary, internet-explorer-11, multipartform-data, worker

I'm trying to send a `multipart/form-data` from a worker with IE. I've already done it with Chrome, Firefox, Safari using `formData` objects (not supported IE, I need a manual one)

The binary data I'm sending is a crypto-js encrypted data. With `formData` objects I do:

```
var enc = new Buffer(encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64), 'base64');
formData.append("userFile" , new Blob([finalEncrypted], {type: 'application/octet-binary'}), 'encrypted')
this works fine generating a multipart like this(missed some parts of it):
```

request headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:30194
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=WebKitFormBoundary0.gjepwugw5cy58kt9
```

body:

```
--WebKitFormBoundary0.gjepwugw5cy58kt9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userFile"; filename="encrypted"
Content-Type: binary
```

all binary data

```
--WebKitFormBoundary0.cpe3c80eodgc766r--
```

With the manual `multipart/form-data`:

```
IE11 doesn't accept readAsBinaryString(deprecated)
```

I would like to avoid sending base64 encoded data(readAsDataURL)(33% payload)

The binary data I'm sending is a crypto-js encrypted data.
I'm trying:

```
finalEncrypted = new Buffer(encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64), 'base64');
```

then in my manual multipart I tried to convert the buffer to a binary string:

```
item.toString('binary')
```

the multipart result looks looks this:

```
--WebKitFormBoundary642013568702052
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="encrypted"
Content-Type: binary
```

all binary data

```
ÐçÀôpRö3§]g7,UOÂmR¤¼ÚS"Ê÷UcíMÆÎÚà/,hy¼øsËÂú@WcGvºÆÞ²i¨¬Ç~÷®}éá?'é·J]þ3«áEÁÞ,4üBçðºÇª bUÈú4
T\Ãõ=òEnýR  _[1J\O-ïÇ¹ C¨\Ûøü^%éÓÁóJNÓï¹LsXâx>\aÁV×Þ^÷·{|­'
```

On the .NET server we check the hash calculated on client versus calculated on server. Server reply that hashes doesn't match. This makes me think that I'm not sending the file correctly.

Comment: coming back to this issue, I've decided to put back of the worker the processed data if user is an IE, and send it from there. so with my encrypted stuff:
<pre>`code`new Buffer(encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64), 'base64')`code`

Comment: coming back to this issue, I've decided to put back of the worker the processed data if user is an IE, and send it from there. so with my encrypted stuff:
<code>
var e =new Buffer(encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64), 'base64')//i'm using browserify if not would be:
var e =new Uint8Array(encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64).buffer
var toExport = new Blob([e], {type: 'application/octet-binary'})
</code>
ie11 has some bug with blobs from workers...

Comment: this way IE gets out of memory. :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not yet get a solution, at least you did not post it here if you had one.

On my end I use jQuery which handles the low level nitty gritty of the actual post.

It may be that you are doing one small thing wrong and IE fails on it. Since you do not show what you used with FormData. It is rather difficult to see whether you had a mistake in there.

```
// step 1. setup POST data
var data = new FormData();
data.append("some_variable_name", "value_for_that_variable");
data.append("some_blob_var_name", my_blob);
data.append("some_file_var_name", my_file);

// step 2. options
var ajax_options =
    {
        method: "POST",
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        error: function(jqxhr, result_status, error_msg)
        {
            // react on errors
        },
        success: function(data, result_status, jqxhr)
        {
            // react on success
        },
        complete: function(jqxhr, result_status)
        {
            // react on completion (after error/success callbacks)
        },
        dataType: "xml" // server is expected to return XML only
    };

// step 3. send
jQuery.ajax(uri, ajax_options);
```

Step 1.

Create a `FormData` object and fills the form data, that includes variables and files. You may even add *blobs* (JavaScript objects, will be transformed to `JSON` if I'm correct.)

Step 2.

Create an `ajax_options` object to your liking. Although here I show your the `method`, `processData`, `data`, `contentType` as they must be in case you want to send a `FormData`. At least, that works for me... It may be possible to change some of those values.

The dataType should be set to whatever type you expect in return.

Step 3.

Send the request using the [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function from the jQuery library. It will build the proper header and results as required for the client's browser.